# Set cookie to expire in 24 hours

Tags: javascript, setcookie

A form has the following code to prevent multiple form submissions:

```
function AllowNoDups() { var cookie_ls = document.cookie; if (cookie_ls.indexOf(document.location) > -1) {
  alert("You've already submitted a free meter request. Thank you for your interest!  ");
  return false; } else { document.cookie = 'username=' + value; + 'expires=' + var now = new Date(); var time = now.getTime(); time += 3600 * 1000; now.setTime(time); document.cookie = 'username=' + value + '; expires=' + now.toGMTString() + '; path=/';; + 'path = /' document.cookie =  "; path=/newform.php; expires=Sun, 1-Jan-2040 00:00:01 GMT;"; return true;};};
```

While the code works, I would rather set the cookie to expire after 24 hours have elapsed, as opposed to specifying a date at which the cookie would expire. How would I go about accomplishing this? Thank you!

Comment: What's to stop me from clearing my cookies and submitting again? My point is, make sure you do this check server-side as well if you aren't already.

Comment: Change time += 3600 * 1000; to time += (24*60*60*1000)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `max-age` attribute. See this wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age).

> As an alternative to setting cookie expiration as an absolute
>   date/time, RFC 6265 allows the use of the Max-Age attribute to set the
>   cookie’s expiration as an interval of seconds in the future, relative
>   to the time the browser received the cookie.

Comment: Unfortunately IE 6,7,8 do not support the max-age attribute and as that is over 80% of the user base it's not really a solution I can deploy.  Thank you for your prompt response though!

Comment: Indeed this can be a solution nowadays, since IE 6,7,8 is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function and pass the parameter as per your requirement..

```
function callcookie(name,value,days){
  if(days){
      var d=new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
      var expires = "; expires="+d.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

Comment: Basically we can just pass parameters as createCookie('myCookie', '12345', 1);